# Jquery Mobile - Popup Menu in Header

Tags: jquery-mobile, android-webview

I have the following header in my JQM page to have popup menu when tapping `option`.

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
    <div><a href="#"><img src="custom-icon.png" class="ui-btn-left" width="32" height="32"/></a></div>

    <h1>HOME</h1>

    <a href="#main-menu" class="ui-btn-right" data-rel="popup" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext">Option</a>
    <div data-role="popup" id="main-menu">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="a">
            <li><a href="menu1" data-theme="c">MENU 1</a>
            <li><a href="menu2" data-theme="c">MENU 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works but it sometimes need to be tapped many times in my android device. The JQM page was used in android-webview. How to solve tapping issue?

THanks

Comment: tapping many times. Sounds like problem is in event handling.

Comment: Can you post your script for handling tap event?

Comment: no event handling was done since that is Jquery Mobile page.

Comment: thats the only code involve...

Comment: @ JR Galia `need to be tapped many times in my android device` seems to be the issue of event bubbling. Check the answer below.

Comment: @KishorSubedi, didn't solved my problem...

Answer (score 0):

In my suggestion you have to stop event bubbling. In `jQuery` you can do this by:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

So in my suggestion write a handler function for the click event for menu link popup.

Make this change in the `JQM` webview page

```
<a href="#" id="my_link" class="ui-btn-right" data-rel="popup" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext">Option</a>
```

And better bind your link in the .ready(), you should try to avoid `Javascript` code in the `DOM` for better maintainability.

```
$('#my_link').live('tap',function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#main-menu').popup('open');
});
```

**EDIT:**

```
$('#YOUR_PAGE_ID').live( 'pageinit',function(event){
    $('#my_link').live('tap',function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('#main-menu').popup('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: im already doing that one. I notice removing `data-iconpos="notext"` might help but with `option` text in the menu. :-(